# How to function switch Button for if else in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to disable text editing if switch button is off and vice versa.
I created something like..:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent newxml = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        newxml.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(newxml);
        TextView displayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayText);
        displayText.setText(message);
        String someText = "Your Message";
        TextView yourMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourMessage);
        yourMessage.setText(someText);
    } }
```

If `switch` is off the variable `editText` i.e `EditText` should not be editable.
Here's my app 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8CHi.jpg).

Comment: Where are you having trouble ? In making a if else structure : [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html). In listening to switch checked event [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton#java). In making the editText unavailable : [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setEnabled(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

Create onCheck changed listener for the switch and do it one line:

```
myTextBox.setEnabled(mySwitch.isChecked());
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this simply by following :
1) Reference the switch & Edittext first
2) Handle listener for switch and enable/disable edittext

```
Switch switch = findViewById(R.id.switch);
EditText etInput = findViewById(R.id.etInput);
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // true if the switch is in the On position
        if(isChecked){
           etInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
           etInput.setFocusable(true);
        }else{
           etInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
           etInput.setFocusable(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: my `CompoundButton buttonView` is red, what should I do?